# How do I get PowerAutomate to update a seperate column in a SharePoint list when another column is updated to a choice?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I am trying to get PowerAutomate to put a date/time stamp in a column when a status column is updated. The status column is tied to a SharePoint 'board' and the goal is to update the corresponding status column with today's date when the user moves a card from one column to the next.

I tried nested IF statements and the Case condition. I made sure to use the column's Value in comparing statuses. I tried quotes... The thing is that it works sometimes and updates the date but most of the time it doesn't work at all.

I am using the 'Update Item' SharePoint function... I have permissions to the list... I am at a complete loss but sure it's something simple.

Here is what the Case setup looks like:

[image: PowerAutomate Setup for SharePoint List showing case statement]

I am expecting it to add the current date and time to the corresponding status column. Each status item from the list choice has it's own column which is formatted as date/time in the sharepoint list. When the user moves a card, it updates the choice column for the board and I want a timestamp to be written to the records status column for a given status.

Again, each status has it's own column. Ideally this will allow us to see how much time is spent in each status.

Here's the update fx: it's

```
parseDateTime(utcNow())
```

For whatever reason `utcNow()` didn't work on it's own:

[image]

Comment: You got an error or something?!?

Comment: It straight up doesn't work most of the time. I change the value in column A and no date gets written to column B or C or D.

Comment: Please also detail what 'doesn't work' means: share also pictures of flow runs when it worked and when it didn't. Also, since your logic involves updating the same item that triggered the flow run, you may also be looking at duplicate flow runs.

Comment: It looks like it was just slow. Now everything is working. It takes a minute to update the date still, but it does update. If I move the item too fast, then it doesn't update. It's going to be a training issue for my users, but it should still work for us. I am going to close this question. Thanks for looking at this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was just slow. Now everything is working. It takes a minute to update the date still, but it does update. If I move the item too fast, then it doesn't update. It's going to be a training issue for my users, but it should still work for us. I am going to close this question. Thanks for looking at this!